# python numpy condition to find a perticular pattern witin a file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a input file like this,

B
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B

I have 2000 files (input-1, input-2 .... input-2000) like this with different "C" and "B" ordering. I only need those files where there are at least 10 or more "C" between two "B".
Please suggest a numpy python script for that.

Thank you

Comment: the files have each letter in one line?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried for this.

Comment: Yes the files have each letter in one line @FlavioMoraes

Comment: @SerialLazer, I am very new in python coding. So, I'm not sure what sure what to start. If someone give me some answers I can work on that.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Asking outright for a Python script to solve this problem is cheating on your homework.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is using regular expression (regex). After reading the file regex can look if there is a match in the file text where there is a `B`, at least 10 `C` and another `B`. Since they are in different lines and the signal to jump line is `\n`, what regex has really search for is if there is a `B\n`, at least 10 `C\n` and another `B`. The code in regex for this is `"B\n(C\n){10,}B\n"`. So I tested the following code to open a file named `test.txt` and verify if there was a match for the regular expression in that:

```
import re

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.read()

if re.search("B\n(C\n){10,}B\n", text):
    print('file has more than 10 consecutives lines with C between two Bs')
```

please try this an be sure that the `.txt` file is in the same folder where you saved your python script. Besides that, to check 2000 files you will have to make a loop between all files. I suggest you search how to do that and try by yourself. A tip is that you can use `os.listdit` to get the names of all files and folders in the same folder as your python script.